# how to get current module id in helper file using joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I need to display the categories in basic options. So i need to fetch the categories form database using the module id. how to get current module id in helper file using joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

```
$module->id
```

I was looking for same answer and found it in [Joomla forums](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1480551#p1480551).